# Adjusting the Brightness of the Official Touchscreen Display

Tags: raspbian, display, raspbian-jessie, touchscreen

Is there a way to adjust the brightness of the official touchscreen display? I couldn't find a definite answer. I'm running the latest release of Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The driver for the screen provides an interface through `/sys/`. To turn the screen on you can use the command:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

and to turn it off:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

the brightness can be adjusted using:

```
echo n > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness
```

where `n` is some value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Just small typo... rpi-backlight should be rpi_backlight for the brightness

Comment: Note that the 'brightness' setting only works on v1.1 LCD hardware.
on v1.0, the control is binary, < 128 are "off", >= 128 are "on" see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49822/official-touchscreen-brightness

Comment: If you get "Permission denied" errors, try with `sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"` (from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=848197#p848197)

Comment: What if the folder `rpi_backlight` or the file `bl_power` don't exist? It's the case with openplotter so none of this works

Answer (score 12):

I've made a Python package for this: [github.com/linusg/rpi-backlight](http://github.com/linusg/rpi-backlight). Now you don't need to implement this yourself anymore.

[image: Example]

*(GIF is outdated because API was changed quite a bit in v2, sorry... Below example is correct )*

Works basically like the above, example:

```py
>>> from rpi_backlight import Backlight
>>>
>>> backlight = Backlight()
>>> backlight.brightness
100
>>> backlight.brightness = 50
>>> backlight.brightness
50
>>>
>>> with backlight.fade(duration=1):
...     backlight.brightness = 0
...
>>> backlight.fade_duration = 0.5
>>> # subsequent `backlight.brightness = x` will fade 500ms
>>>
>>> backlight.power
True
>>> backlight.power = False
>>> backlight.power
False
>>>
```

It has a GUI, a CLI and a simple Python API :)

Answer (score 0):

If you like an application, you can use the code below. I'll give detailed instructions of how to use it.

- create a new file `/home/pi/brightnesschanger.py`
- copy and paste the following code into that file (Explanation: this is the program for changing brightness):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

MAX_BRIGHTNESS = 255
CONFIG_FILE = "/sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness"



def runApp ():
  # root window
  root = tk.Tk ()
  root.geometry ('330x100')
  root.resizable (True, True)
  root.title ('Raspberry Pi 7" screen brightness')

  root.columnconfigure (0, weight=1)
  root.columnconfigure (1, weight=3)


  # slider current value
  current_value = tk.IntVar ()


  def get_current_value ():
    return (current_value.get ()/MAX_BRIGHTNESS*100)


  def slider_changed (event):
    value_percent = "{: .2f} %".format (get_current_value ())
    value_label.configure (text=value_percent)
    try:
      with open(CONFIG_FILE, "w") as file:
        value = current_value.get ()
        file.write (str(value))
    except:
        print ("ERROR: Could not set brightness")
        #probably file does not exist

  # slider
  slider = ttk.Scale (
  root,
  from_=12,
  to=MAX_BRIGHTNESS,
  orient='horizontal', # vertical
  command=slider_changed,
  variable=current_value

  )

  slider.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'x')

  # current value label
  # current_value_label = ttk.Label (root, text='Current Value:' )
  # current_value_label.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'x')


  # value label
  value_label = ttk.Label (root, text=get_current_value ())
  value_label.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'x')


  try:
    with open(CONFIG_FILE, "r") as file:
      value = file.readline ()
      slider.set (int (value))
  except:
    print ("Error: Could not read brightness")

  root.mainloop ()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
  runApp ()
```

- Save and close the file
- Unfortunately you cannot double-click that file to run the program.
- We will now create a file on the Desktop, that you can doubleclick to start the program
- Open a text editor and paste the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Brightness
Comment=Change brightness of Raspberry Pi 7 inch official screen
Exec=sudo python3 /home/pi/brightnesschanger.py
Path=/home/pi
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility
```

- Save the file under `home/pi/Brightness.Desktop`
- *Security notice*: The application will be started with root privileges. If you use your pi only for playing around, this should be no problem. Otherwise you should figure out if this is a problem for you.