# Setting official touchscreen display boot-time brightness

Tags: boot, display, touchscreen, config.txt

I've got an official display, and having found other questions about [setting the brightness](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/46225) I know I can change the brightness, and make a script that will run on boot, but that means the screen will start at default brightness and eventually be turned down. Is there a way to set the boot-time brightness value (such as a `config.txt` setting)?

The value that seems to be 'just right' for me is `12`, so having it start at `255` (not sure if that's the default) is far too bright.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for not being able to lower the brightness at boot you could [make the whole boot sequence black](https://scribles.net/silent-boot-up-on-raspbian-stretch/).

1. Disable the rainbow by adding this on a *new line* in `/boot/config.txt`

   ```
   disable_splash=1
   ```
2. Disable the splash image

   ```
   sudo systemctl mask plymouth-start.service
   ```

   *Or* just make a darker version by replacing `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/pix/splash.png`.
3. Remove the RPi logo(s) by adding this *on the same line* in  `/boot/cmdline.txt`

   ```
   logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0
   ```

   It will at least stay black until the sysfs brightness setting is applied.
4. Set brightness with `sysfsutils` which you'll have to install with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sysfsutils
   ```

   then add to `/etc/sysfs.conf` the following line:

   ```
   class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness = 12
   ```