# Pi Touchscreen Dim with Chromium kiosk -- how can I switch on/off/dim through REACT or NODE.JS commands?

Tags: touchscreen, node.js, chromium, kiosk

Auto switching touchscreen on/off is critical for our project with 9 RPi's in large home with 6 bedrooms, living, study, play room, etc. The app is **React** on **Chromium kiosk** mode, running **Node.js** handling temp/humidity sensors, motion sensor, window-open (3 to 8 windows/doors per room) -- to be used in tropical weather. A/C heat pump runs with hot/cold water, and in each room a separate fan coil supplies cold or hot air, using RPi touchscreen as thermostat on/off control (***far more sophisticated than Nest***).

Just started testing "pi-touchscreen-dimmer", which dims light when touchscreen is left for n-seconds...

**My question:** is there a way to control the dimmer level from either a local Node (firing socket messages), or from Chromium (React) sending commands to a dimmer tool ?

For example, if someone opens a window/door, the RPi gets a "window-open" signal, for which I want to brighten screen to 255x, then display a warning to inform guests that fan coil's cold water supply will be cut off (no chilling, fan only), maybe in 30 or 60 seconds...

*P.S. I'll post the whole project on GitHub soon... making good progress !*

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46225/adjusting-the-brightness-of-the-official-touchscreen-display) you will see that brightness can by controlled with a simple echo command **assuming** you have the official Raspberry Pi screen.  If not please document what screen you are using.

It basically sends data to `/sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness` with a value between 0 and 255

This saves a lot of inter-program communication by just either writing to this as a file or using a command shell to run the echo command.